Create a navigation bar with bullets in Beamer where each bullet corresponds to a frame in the current section
I'm using Goettingen theme, but it does not display bullets below the name of the section, with number of bullets corresponding to number of frames of that section. Is there a way to add them or it is the theme that does not allow it? 
Thank you!
